# Alternative to SQLite INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... WHERE ... DO UPDATE SET

Tags: sqlite

I'm running an application that uses SQLite3 version 3.7.17 on Linux. It's erroring out on this statement:

```
INSERT INTO taxa (taxon_id, rank, parent_id) VALUES (?,?,?)
        ON CONFLICT (taxon_id) WHERE parent_id is NULL
        DO UPDATE SET parent_id=excluded.parent_id,rank=excluded.rank
```

But the same code runs on version 3.28.0. Is there another way of writing this statement so it can run on 3.7.17?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ON CONFLICT...` or [`UPSERT`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html) was added to SQLite in version 3.24.0.

In earlier versions you can get similar functionality with 2 separate statements.

First try to update the table:

```
UPDATE taxa 
SET rank = ?, parent_id = ?
WHERE taxon_id = ?;
```

If a row with the `taxon_id = ?` exists it will be updated.
If it does not exist nothing will happen.

Then try to insert the new row with `INSERT OR IGNORE`:

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO taxa (taxon_id, rank, parent_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?);
```

If a row with the `taxon_id = ?` exists nothing will happen (I assume that `taxon_id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table or at least defined as `UNIQUE`).
If it does not exist then the new row will be inserted.